# Operating Systems that save registers in PCB

Tags: operating-system, cpu-registers

I've been teaching OS for several years, and as several textbook say and the most websites, the processor states is stored in the PCB including registers. However when I look real world examples, all real OSs that I can find source code to seem to store the registers on the kernel stack for the process. Anybody have an example of a real world OS that stores the registers in the PCB?

Comment: The stack pointer is stored in the PCB so, even in those cases you describe, the registers are still, effectively, stored in the PCB, though indirectly:)

Comment: ...put another way, you cannot save a stack pointer by pushing it:)

Comment: While true the SP has to be stored in the PCB, the diagrams in multiplet text books  and websites show a block in the PCB and say registers. They specifically identify accumulators, index registers, general purpose registers in the description. It is true that some of the aux registers such as FP and MM registers are in the PCB in Linux, but the main processor state registers are on the Stack. I'd like some idea if there is an OS that uses the PCB for the general purpose registers rather than the stack. Doesn't have to be x86 based. Could be PPC, ARM or any other architecture.

Comment: I don't know of any.  It's difficult to come up with any other clean solution.  The user regs need saving somewhere, pushing requires no operands, (other than the register, maybe, if there is no PUSHA).  To store the regs in a control block, that would mean retrieving the address of the block without corrupting any regs, so some would have to be pushed anyway:(

Comment: 'diagrams in multiplet text books and websites show' lol!  This may be another case where multiple boks/sites are all wrong:)   There is precedent for this, unfortunately - many 'intro to threads' books/sites are just dire, riddled with incestuous copypasta, cargo-cult join, conceptual errors, terrible designs and depressingly bad advice:(

Comment: I agree, it does seem like a case where the same explanation has spread. I'd like the course material to be closer to modern systems. However even the more recent books I've been sent by publishers seem to say the same thing. The only reason I think it may have been used is for systems without kernel stacks, using the PCB might prevent stack overflow if the stack was close to the limit. I'd like to have some foundation before I go back in to the classroom and say the text is wrong. Right now, the best I can do is say linux/bsd/darwin use the kernel stack.

Comment: Well, thinking a bit about it, if a seperate kernel stack is required by the design, and every thread requires a control block and a stack, why not allocate the lot together?  With an x86-style push-down stack, the TCB proper would be at the top of the allocated area and the stack beneath.  The whole lot could then be described as the 'TCB' and the pushed user regs would be part of it.  Initialize the top, load the stack with a simulated interrupt frame with the thread start IP, link in to a ready queue, do a scheduler run and a 'POPA IRET' sets it off:(

Comment: Thats true. Redo the diagrams to match that concept by putting the registers at the bottom of the PCB so that they are on the stack. I wanted to dive a bit deeper into the context switch mechanism next time, although that means I have to take some time away from something else. in the course.